# React Changing values of drop down according to selected values in other drop-down lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a 3 react input fields filling data to a useState Hook

```
                 <FormControl fullWidth>
                    <InputLabel>Primary Goal</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                      
                      name='goalOne'
                      id='goalOne'
                      value={current.goalOne}
                      onChange={onChange}
                    >
                      <MenuItem id='goalOne' value={10}>
                        Retirment
                      </MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem id='goalOne' value={20}>
                        Children Education
                      </MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem id='goalOne' value={30}>
                        Vacation
                      </MenuItem>
                      </Select>
                  </FormControl>
```

the state looks like this:

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState({
  goalOne: '10',
  goalTwo: '20',
  goalThree: '30',
});
```

and the onChange function is like this:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  setCurrent({ ...current, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

If the user choose goalOne as retirement while goalTwo is already set as retirement, goalTwo should change to what goalOne was previously.
I tried saving previous values in another state and then use useEffect Hook to run some logic but my noob code seems to be a mess.

here is an example of what i tried:

```
const onChangeGoals = (e) => {
    let prevValue = current[e.target.name];
    setPreviousGoals({ ...previousGoals, [e.target.name]: prevValue });
    setCurrent({ ...current, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const [previousGoals, setPreviousGoals] = useState({
    goalOne: 10,
    goalTwo: 10,
    goalThree: 10,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (current.goalOne === current.goalTwo) {
      setCurrent({ goalTwo: previousGoals.goalOne });
    } else if (current.goalOne == current.goalThree) {
      setCurrent({ goalThree: previousGoals.goalOne });
 
    }
  }, [current.goalOne]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that if a value (i.e Retirement, Vacation etc) already exists in any of the current values then it needs to interchanged with the value of the new selection. Here is a sample for the same -

```
const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState({
  goalOne: '10',
  goalTwo: '20',
  goalThree: '30',
});

const onChangeGoals = (e) => {
  const keyChanged = e.target.name;
  const keyWhoseValueIsRepeated = Object.keys(selectedValues).find(key => selectedValues[key] === e.target.value);
  let newValues = { ...selectedValues, [keyChanged]: e.target.value };
  if (keyWhoseValueIsRepeated) {
    newValues[keyWhoseValueIsRepeated] = selectedValues[keyChanged];
  }
  setSelectedValues(newValues);
}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Works like magic. Thank you so much. I will read more about the Object.keys find function but i totally understand the logic followed there. have a long way still to grasp JS it seems :) Thank you again saved my day!